# MySQL - Select DISTINCT with Count Of That Distinct , Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I turn the following query into the distinct result but with a count of the words returned with the same result? I could do a separate query, but there's a way to combine them.

table is simple, it's just ( id, info, language )

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`language`) FROM `info`
```

Easy enough, returns all of the languages that are unique. However,
how do I count how many words have the language, and return within the same query.

Example of the results it would need to return

language | count of how many words are of this language
langa | 20000
langb | 10000
langc | 4000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use grouping if you want to achieve the result with aggregating the data. You can use COUNT function in this case:

```
SELECT `language`, COUNT(`id`) FROM `words`
GROUP BY `language`
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `count()`.

This will return the number of words per language

```
select language, count(word) as n_words
from tbl_word
group by language
```

If you want the number of *unique* words per language, then use this:

```
select language, count(distinct word) as n_unique_words
from tbl_word
group by language
```